# Parallel resolve of Hibernate UserType when returning via criteria.list()

Tags: hibernate, jaxb, criteria

Built a UserType in Hibernate.....

That unmarshalls/marshalls JAXB annotated objects into string data that is feed into an XML column (inside DB2).  Rolling data between strings and Pojos take time....around 7ms (with or without validation).  Problem is that if I have a results set of 20 odd objects the rolling of data is done sequentially.  20 * 7ms is a 140ms which is a lot just to pull out 20 elements from a table.  Using the Hibernate Criteria and the list method to return data.

Is there anyway to process the results that Hibernate gets from the JDBC pipe in parallel?  So that the 7ms is distributed over parallel processing reducing my responses time down to the time JAXB needs to transform?

Have searched around via Google but haven't seen anything...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. My first thought is to try to model it as a `Future<Thing>`. Your UserType could submit a task to an `Executor` and return the `Future`.

You will no doubt have some interesting issues around timing (as with all concurrency), plus implementing the rest of the UserType interface (ie. equals, hashCode etc) become much harder.

Comment: The guaranty that the data is intact when handed over from Hibernate to the user's code is a must.  So with individual futures the immediate problem is a synchronous response whereby all of the objects in the result set have valid properties (i.e. in my case a parsed string as a JAXB object).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution would be to abandon the user type and model the property as an `InputStream`

```
public Thing {
    // use field access level
    private InputStream blob;

    @Tranisent       
    private Future<That> that;

    private static final ExecutorService executor = ExecutorService.newCachedThreadPool();

    public Future<That> getThat(){
        if( that == null ) {
            // lazily submit the creation to the executor
            that = executor.submit(new Callable<That>{/* implement call() */});
        } 
        return that;
    }
}
```

Think this might be a little bit more approachable that the UserType of `Future<That>`

Note when you get a list of `Thing` you first need to prime the objects before actually attempting to access the values:

```
for( Thing thing: listOfThings ){
    thing.getThat() ; // for side effects
}                                        

for( Thing thing: listOfThings ){
    That that = thing.getThat().get();
}
```

There are a couple of issues with this.

1. There isn't a clear life cycle for the Executor. i.e. how will it be shutdown
2. There is no guarantee that the first item in the list will be the first to return a result, maybe using a `ExecutorCompletationService` would provide a better solution

Comment: Haven't used completion services before but it is worth a look and in regard to "order" the list of queried objects stays in order.  If I recap your suggestion: skip the UserType sending the data (string) into a property (which should be fast thus speeding up Hiberante and no tricking is needed with Hibernate) then either an ExecutorService or CompletionService does the actual marshall/unmarshall step through a singleton static.  Will test to make sure that caller isn't hit with processing cost.